# select2 multiple values store in database in asp.net C#

Tags: c#, asp.net

I want to print value multiple in asp.net c# : 
**Default.aspx**

```
<asp:DropDownList runat="server" ID="ddlSkills" CssClass="form-control" multiple="multiple" >
    <asp:ListItem Value="HTML5">HTML5</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Value="CSS3">CSS3</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Value="JavaScript">JavaScript</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Value="C#.NET">C#.NET</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Value="Java">Java</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Value="PHP">PHP</asp:ListItem>
</asp:DropDownList>
<br /><br />
<asp:Button runat="server" ID="btnSave" CssClass="btn btn-primary" Text="Save" OnClick="btnSave_Click" />
```

I just print one data form multiple data : **Default.aspx.cs** page

```
protected void btnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string message = "";
        foreach(ListItem item in ddlSkills.Items)
        {
            if(item.Selected)
            {
                message += item.Text;
            }
        }
        ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this.GetType(), "alert", "alert('" + message + "');", true);
    }
```

Comment: What is exactly the problem? Are you getting some kind of error?

Comment: Do you mean to alert each selected Item

Comment: Yeah.. alert selected item is only one.. but I want to more select item